# Do I have to prove that $ \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty \bigcup_{n=1}^k A_n = \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This is not a fascinating question but in solving a HW problem, one of my intermediate steps requires transitioning from one to the other to complete the solution.

Not sure how to prove this?

Comment: This is true, and the proof goes as it normally goes for most set equalities: suppose $x\in\text{LHS}$ and prove $x\in\text{RHS}$ and the other way round.

Comment: Take an element in the left-hand side $x\in \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{n=1}^{k}A_n$ then $x\in \bigcup_{n=1}^{k}A_n$ for some $k$ so that....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Stinking Bishop suggests, "$\subseteq$" and "$\supseteq$" is the way to go:

Let $x \in LHS$ be arbitrary, by definition there is a $k \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $x \in \cup^k_{n = 1} A_n$, so by definition there is an $n \in \{1, \ldots, k\}$ s.t. $x \in A_k$. Hence $LHS \subseteq \cup^{\infty}_{k = 1} A_k$.

Let $x \in \cup^{\infty}_{k = 1} A_k$ be arbitrary, then by definition there is a $k \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $x \in  A_k$. So since $A_k \subseteq \cup^k_{n = 1} A_k \subseteq LHS$ we have $x \in LHS$.

Comment: Thanks. In general, is the correct logic $x \in \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k$ $\iff$ $x \in A_l$ for some $l \in \mathbb{N}$? Or is the logic $x \in \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k$ $\implies$ $x \in A_l$ for some $l \in \mathbb{N}$ ?

Comment: It's an equivalence: by definition an element is in the union of sets if and only if it is in any of them, so $x \in \cup^{\infty}_{k = 1} A_k \Leftrightarrow x \in A_k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Also, in your comment you used, $l$ as an index - which is fine - but be sure that $A_l$ is one of the set which comprise the union.